# GCloud custom image upload failure due to size or permissions

Tags: gcloud, gcloud-cli

I've been trying to upload two custom images for some time now and I have failed repeatedly. During the import process the Google application always responds with the message that the Compute Engine Default Service Account does not have the role 'roles/compute.storageAdmin'. However, I have both assigned it using the CLI as the webinterface.

Notable is that the application throws this error during resizing of the disk. The original size of the disk is about 10GB, however, it tries to convert it to a 1024GB (!) disk. This got me thinking, could it be that this is too big for the application, hence it throwing the error it lacks permissions?

As a follow up questions, I have not found any options to set the size of the disk (not in the CLI nor in the webapp). Does anybody know of such options?

Here is the error message I have recieved:

```
ate-import-3ly9z": StatusMatch found: "Import: Resizing temp-translation-disk-3ly9z to 1024GB in projects/0000000000000/zones/europe-west4-a."
[import-and-translate]: 2020-05-01T07:46:30Z Error running workflow: step "import" run error: step "wait-for-signal" run error: WaitForInstancesSignal FailureMatch found for "inst-importer-import-and-translate-import-3ly9z": "ImportFailed: Failed to resize disk. The Compute Engine default service account needs the role: roles/compute.storageAdmin'"
[import-and-translate]: 2020-05-01T07:46:30Z Serial-output value -> target-size-gb:1024
[import-and-translate]: 2020-05-01T07:46:30Z Serial-output value -> source-size-gb:7
[import-and-translate]: 2020-05-01T07:46:30Z Serial-output value -> import-file-format:vmdk
[import-and-translate]: 2020-05-01T07:46:30Z Workflow "import-and-translate" cleaning up (this may take up to 2 minutes).
[import-and-translate]: 2020-05-01T07:47:34Z Workflow "import-and-translate" finished cleanup.
[import-image] 2020/05/01 07:47:34 step "import" run error: step "wait-for-signal" run error: WaitForInstancesSignal FailureMatch found for "inst-importer-import-and-translate-import-3ly9z": "ImportFailed: Failed to resize disk. The Compute Engine default service account needs the role: roles/compute.storageAdmin'"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/compute-image-tools/gce_vm_image_import:release" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.images.import) build a9ccbeac-92c5-4457-a784-69d486e85c3b completed with status "FAILURE"
```

Thanks for your time!

EDIT: Not sure but I'm farily certain this is due to the 1024GB being too big. I've uploaded a 64GB without any issues using the same methods. For those who read after me, that's most likely the issue (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message with the [import of virtual disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks) have 2 root causes:

1.- Cloud Build and/or Compute engine and/or your User account did not have the correct IAM roles to perform these tasks. You can verify them [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/import/importing-virtual-disks#enable-cloud-build).

- Cloud Build SA roles needed:

  - roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator
  - roles/compute.admin
  - roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
- Compute Engine SA roles needed:

  - roles/compute.storageAdmin
  - roles/storage.objectViewer
- User Account roles needed:

  - roles/storage.admin
  - roles/viewer
  - roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin

2.- " Not sure but I'm fairly certain this is due to the 1024GB being too big" The disk quota you have is less than 1T. The normal disk quota is 250-500 GB so that could be why by importing a 64 GB disk you encounter no problem.

You can check your quota in step 1 of [this document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota); If you need to request more, you can follow steps 2 to 7.